# How to use the 'comments_number' filter?

Tags: comments, filters, hooks

I'm not sure how to use [this filter](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/comments_number?version=3.5&file=wp-includes/comment-template.php). Could someone show me an example? I'm trying to change `('0', '1', '%')` to `('0 Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments')`.

I'm using this function to get the comments number.

```
    function lpe_get_comments_number( $anchor='#comments' ) {
        $return = '<a class="comments-number-link" href="' . get_permalink() . $anchor . '">';
        $return .= get_comments_number(); // '0', '1', '%'
        $return .= '</a>';
        return $return;
    }
```

I know I could just set the arguments here and call it a day, but I was hoping to store my custom functions away in a different file and handle their settings from the themes functions.php.

Comment: You can use comments_number function to acheve this. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number

Comment: I'm trying to set the $args in the functions file, so that all comments_number() functions have the same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter you mention is used by the end of [`get_comments_number_text`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments_number_text/). As you can see from the source the number of comments is passed through the filter, allowing you to completely change the default text. Like this:

```
add_filter ('comments_number', 'wpse89257_comments_number', 10, 2);
function wpse89257_comments_number ($output, $number) {
  if ($number == 0) $output = '0 Comments';
  elseif ($number == 1) $output = '1 Comment';
  else $output = $number . ' Comments';
  return $output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put functions like `get_permalink()` or `get_comments_number()` in a function, then you have to make the `$comments` and `$post` vars accessible. [Read more about the scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Normally you will do it with a `global` keyword. An easy example: retriving the permalink

```
function my_personal_permalink( $anchor = '' ) {
  global $post;
  $return = get_permalink( $post->ID );
  $return .= $anchor;

  return $return;
}
```

This is a *very simple example*. `get_permalink()` need some information from which post it should generate the permalink. So we have to make the 'post' accessible inside the function. This will be done with `global $post;`, it will make the actual post data accessible. `get_permalink()` need the post ID, we pass it with `$post->ID`

If you use template functions inside a function, then you have to explore which data the template functions need (post, comment, database connection (`$wpdb`), etc.) and pass them as argument.

Comment: The problem is not with the function, the function works. I'm looking for an example on how to use a filter with it.

Comment: You mean `apply_filters()` and `add_filter()`?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on my first answer, I think you wish to apply filters.

```
function lpe_get_comments_number( $anchor='#comments' ) {
  $return = '<a class="comments-number-link" href="' . get_permalink() . $anchor . '">';

  $args = array(
    'zero' => 'Zero comments',
    'one' => 'One comment',
    'more' => '% Comments'
  );

  $filtered_args = apply_filters( 'choose_your_hook_name', $args );

  // be sure all keys in the filtered args are present and have a valid value
  // this is optional but usefull
  $args = wp_parse_args( $filtered_args, $args );

  $return .= get_comments_number( $args['zero'], $args['one'], $args['more'] ); // '0', '1', '%'

  $return .= '</a>';
  return $return;
}

add_filter( 'choose_your_hook_name', 'your_filter_callback', 1, 1 );

function your_filter_callback( $args ) {
  return array( 'zero' => 'Foo Comments', 'one' => 'Bar Comments' );
}
```

You can also pass additional argument to `apply_filters()` if you want to decide things depending on the passed arguments:

```
$zero = 'Zero Comments';

if ( $today == 'sunday' ) {
  $foo = 'Sunday, yeah!';
} else {
  $foo = '';
  $bar = 'No sunday';
}

$zero = apply_filters( 'choose_your_hook_name', $zero, $foo, $bar );

get_comments_number( $zero, $one, $more );
```

[more code]

```
add_filter( 'choose_your_hook_name', 'your_filter_callback', 1, 3 );

function your_filter_callback( $zero, $foo = '', $bar = '' ) {
  if ( ! empty( $foo ) )
    $zero = 'No comments on sunday!';
  elseif( ! empty( $bar ) )
    $zero = $bar . ', here are % comments';

  return $zero;
}
```